# Error installing anything on Kali 2.0

Tags: linux, software-installation, kali-linux, upgrade, error-handling

I changed from 32bit to 64bit and i cant install anything.
As soon as i installed the OS i used `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`.
Now everything i try to install i get the following error.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
wine is already the newest version (1.8.5-1).
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc-6-multilib : Depends: libc6-dev-i386 (>= 2.11) but it is not going to be installed
 libc6-dev-x32 : Depends: libc6-dev-i386 (= 2.24-8) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Anything i try to install.

Examples: `apt-get install wine`, `apt-get install firmware-iwlwifi`

I am very new to unix.

Comment: You still have links to i386 stuff in your apt lists. Either that, or your apt preferences are still set to want i386 rather than amd64.

Comment: "f you are unfamiliar with Linux generally, if you do not have at least a basic level of competence in administering a system, if you are looking for a Linux distribution to use as a learning tool to get to know your way around Linux, or if you want a distro that you can use as a general purpose desktop installation, Kali Linux is probably not what you are looking for." - http://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux

Comment: Run `apt-get dist-upgrade`

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `apt-get -f install`?

If you check `man apt-get` You will find

```
 -f, --fix-broken
   Fix; attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place. This
   option, when used with install/remove, can omit any packages to permit APT
   to deduce a likely solution. If packages are specified, these have to
   completely correct the problem. The option is sometimes necessary when
   running APT for the first time; APT itself does not allow broken package
   dependencies to exist on a system. It is possible that a system's dependency
   structure can be so corrupt as to require manual intervention (which usually
   means using dselect(1) or dpkg --remove to eliminate some of the offending
   packages). Use of this option together with -m may produce an error in some
   situations. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Fix-Broken.
```